# Tumblr Video post not displaying in Chrome and Firefox but is in Safari?

Tags: css

Currently putting together a Tumblr theme, having a problem with the video post in that the the embedded video from Vimeo is displaying perfectly fine in Safari (8.0 and iOS 8.1) as well as Google Chrome's mobile app. However it is just not displaying on Chrome (v39.0.2171.71) or Firefox (v33.1.1) on my desktop and just shows the black background I've applied to it? Does anybody know what may be going on here?

I have put it as it is on Tumblr here ( [link](http://malmo-theme.tumblr.com) ) and my video post code is as follows:

```
{block:Video}
<section class="e-all d-all c-all b-all a-all">
   <div class="video-player">{Video-700}</div>
   {block:Caption}
     <div class="e3-e6 d3-d6 c4-c7 b4-b7 a4-a7 caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
   </section>
{/block:Video}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS looks like an implementation of the [fluid width video technique](http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) but is missed some properties.

**CSS**

```
.video-player {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.video-player iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

On a side note, I would look at http://fitvidsjs.com/ as either a more solid solution or a guide how to make your own. Videos embeds will not always be a 16:9 ratio.

Comment: Sorry yes I do have the fluid CSS for the video, my CSS is: 

.video-player {padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; background-color: #000000;}

.video-player iframe {width: 100%; height: 100%;}

Is that where I'm going wrong do you think?

Comment: Yep. You need to move the iframe into the area created by `padding-bottom` :D